# Check if Object exists wihout using `if` statement - error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to set `obj['a32']['a']=3232` without using `if` statement and without using `!` to tell compiler to not check?
I tried using `?.` but it throws `The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.(2779)`
Playground: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIG8BQyfINoDWEAngFwDOYUoA5gLqnqEkVW0MgCuAtgEbQBfANyYBmTAgD2ISskm8AVqVTIAvMnTDxE6bIKqA5HADMAJgMjgMABQBCeQsJ0AlFjmKnqzSLGYHTvCMDOlUzMxE-DwI6AH4AOkC4YNDTcPF-aNtE5LDTCKtrDJc3XCLskNyfcSA)

```
interface A{
    [key:string]:{[key:string]:number};
}

const obj:A = {};

const k='a32';
if(!obj[k]){
 obj[k]={};
}

obj[k]['a']=3232; // Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532)

obj[k]?.['a']=3232; // The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.(2779)

obj[k]!['a']=3232; // this works but never checks if obj['a32] is defined


if(obj[k]){
    obj[k]['a']=3232;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you want to avoid using an `if` statement, but you could use the [logical nullish assignment operator `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) instead:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&noFallthroughCasesInSwitch=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnINoDWEAngFzIDOYUoA5gLrkaEnlU0gPkgCuAtgCNoAXwDcWYViwIA9iCrIZAgFbl0AXkxips+WGQFkmgORwAzACZj4rAAolywvWQB+F5ozCAlHlPHnmpaWNroUMgA2EAB04TK09ipeosgA9CmYyOYWTJnkQRbIwoVYQA)

```ts
interface A {
  [key: string]: {[key: string]: number};
}

const obj: A = {};

const k = 'a32';

(obj[k] ??= {})['a'] = 3232;

console.log(obj); // { a32: { a: 3232 } }
```